# Qual deve ser a Query para obter um resultado de tuplas em que o valor de uma coluna seja 'x'?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Eu tenho a seguinte query:

```
$select = "SELECT concat(mid(cpf,1,3),'.',mid(cpf,4,3),'.',mid(cpf,7,3),'-',mid(cpf,10,2)) as cpf, nome, genero, nome_cracha, rg, crm, crm_uf, rua, bairro, cep, cidade,
    estado, telefone, celular, fax, email, cna, ano_titulo_especialista, categoria_inscricao,
    forma_pagamento, dataconfirmacao, data from inscricao order by nome ASC";
```

e eu quero que a variavel $x saiba o valor "categoria_inscricao"(que a query irá mostrar).
Quero isso para fazer o seguinte:

```
if($x == "valor de categoria_inscricao" ){
   ... 
}
```

---

**Editado**

Estou usando um código para converter os valores da tabela para o Excel. Porém eu quer que ao invés de aparecer o valor da coluna, eu consiga mostras que se o valor da coluna for "x" o que irá aparecer no Excel é "y".

Segue o código:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: index.php"); exit;
}
    include("conexao.php");

    $select = "SELECT concat(mid(cpf,1,3),'.',mid(cpf,4,3),'.',mid(cpf,7,3),'-',mid(cpf,10,2)) as cpf, nome, genero, nome_cracha, rg, crm, crm_uf, rua, bairro, cep, cidade,
    estado, telefone, celular, fax, email, cna, ano_titulo_especialista, categoria_inscricao,
    forma_pagamento, dataconfirmacao, data from inscricao order by nome ASC";



    $export = mysql_query($select) or die ("Sql error : ".mysql_error());

    $fields = mysql_num_fields($export);

    $header = "";
    $data = ""; 
    for ( $i = 0; $i<$fields; $i++ )
    {
    $header .= mysql_field_name($export, $i)."\t";
    }

    while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $export ) )
    {
    $line = '';
    foreach( $row as $value )
    {
    if ((!isset($value)) || ($value == ""))
    {
    $value = "\t";
    }
    else
    {
    $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
    $value = '"'.$value.'"'."\t";
    }
    $line .= $value;
    }
    $data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
    }
    $data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );

    if ( $data == "" )
    {
    $data = "\n(0) Records Found!\n";
    }

    $novonome = date('Ymd');

    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$novonome.".xls");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    print "$header\n$data";

    ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem esse exemplo abaixo.
Perceba que no `printf` para comparar ele usa `$row["id"]`, ou  seja, como índice do array ele usa o nome do campo que você retorna.
No seu caso

```
if($row['valor de categoria_inscricao'] == $x)
```

grave isso ...senão grave aquilo.

[mysql_fetch_array()](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password") or
    die("Não foi possível conectar: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mydb");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM mytable");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row["id"], $row["name"]);
}

mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

Comment: aeee ... isso ae man ...haha vlw!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode restringir o valor da pesquisa na query para fazer isso. Por exemplo:

```sql
SELECT nome
FROM inscricao
WHERE categoria_inscricao = <valor desejado>
ORDERBY nome ASC
```

Essa consulta retornará apenas os nomes das linhas cujo valor da `categoria_inscricao` tenha sido pré-definido.

Para mais informações sobre a claúsula `WHERE`, [clique aqui](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_%28SQL%29).

Comment: entendi... mas acho que minha dúvida vai alem ... editei o post para explicar melhor.

Comment: Verdade, vai sim, achei que você só queria retornar o que tivesse no banco com o "valor x".